# How convert for example: "\x3e" to ">" in PHP?

Tags: php

How convert for example: "\x3e" to ">" in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that's a UTF-8 escape sequence, use [`utf8_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php):

```
echo utf8_decode('\x3e'); // >
```

Comment: @user515503: Why don't you try it yourself?